# Ruby on Rails - bin files shebang causing issues (Mac)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bin, shebang

So for the files in the /bin directory of a normal rails installation (bin/rails, bin/rake, bin/bundle), the shebang at the top of the file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
```

But when I run bin/rails, for example, I get the error:

```
env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory
```

When I remove the `.exe` from the end of the shebang, everything works fine.  But I was just curious:

1. Why is this necessary
2. How to deal with versioning, since the other developer working on this doesn't need to remove the .exe.  It's suggested to keep the bin folder in the repo, so I'd prefer to just get the .exe version working if anything.

Comment: are you asking why is the shebang necessary or why is removing the exe necessary? are you running on windows? in cygwin? mac? linux?

Comment: mac. why is removing the .exe necessary. how to deal with in regards to versioning since other developer (who is on windows) doesn't need to remove the .exe.

Comment: Your Rails installation isn't correct if it thinks you need ".exe". Ruby and Rails on Mac OS, when installed correctly won't do that. How did you install Rails on Mac OS?

Comment: it was installed by default. perhaps it got messed up when upgrading from yosemite to el capitan.  any way to revert it to fresh el capitan ruby installation?

Comment: regardless of the outcome of this you should check out something like rvm

Answer (score 2):

There are no .exe files on Mac OS X or on Linux. On those platforms the Ruby executable is just called `ruby`.

For compatibility to those operating systems, your first line should look like this:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env ruby
```